# get app download count from android market

Tags: android, google-play

I can use android-market-api to get nearly all information about my app from  Android Market.

But with published function from android-market-api, I cannot get download count number as it is in the Publisher's page (market.android.com/publish)

Is there any way to get this number with my android market developer account?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Google Analytics in your app (you'll get a lot of useful stats) and then use Analytics API to track download counts and source.

Comment: Why? Try looking at http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the exact numeric download count or a range? Because downloadsCountText (which you can get) will give you the latter.

Answer (score -2):

I'm confusing by how you asked the question. If you have no access to the Google Developer Console, you can only search for it on Google Play and get an estimated range.

If you do, select the app, then click the first tab at left called "Statistics". It will give you a more detailed sales graph.